# How to access the key of the newData server variable?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

(Please see revised question and comment if further clarity is necessary)

## Given this data structure

```
{
  "-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7":true
}
```

### How can I access the first value ( "-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7" ) from within the Firebase Validation Rules when I try to validate the newData?

Below please find my original question.

### Background

Samples online show that the best way to connect Firebase entities is using an index where one collects id's that relate one entity within a node of another entity.

for example;

```
"groups":{ 
...
  "members":{
   "userid-1":true, 
   "userid-2":true
   }
 }
```

I want to publish an index to a node below another entity (queues/queue/tasks) with the following data structure and to validate that data structure with the set of rules described below:

```
{
  "-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7":true
}
```

The data structure is a reference to a task entity (/tasks/task/tid) that I want to associate with a node of a separate entity.

I'm planning on putting those values into a Dictionary and adding it via setValue. When I do this Firebase should apply a validation rule. I want to verify that the identifier is one that exists elsewhere in the database.

> **My Index Will Look Like This**
>   (where the identifiers relate to a set of task id's stored in another location)

```
"queues":{
....
   "K24395498054-p23"{
     "tasks": {
        "-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7":true,
        "-KWjewrkstwqt7Ln-pL3":true,
        "-KWjewgqjdsllfsn-pL5":true
      }
    }
 }
```

But I'm unclear on how to unpack the first value of the newData server variable within the rules when in this case, I have no child identifier.

## Instead of sending a singular value, I am sending a dictionary to Firebase.

**newData in this case should equal**:

```
{
  "-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7":true
}
```

> **Nota Bene** - An interesting side note on this; I'm trying to create an
>   index but reading the setValue documentation. It states that the value
>   would be overwritten. How then can I save the dictionary without
>   overwriting the existing values?

**Rules**:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "queues": {
      ".write":"auth.provider != 'anonymous'",
      "$qid": {
       "members" : {
         //unsure how to access the first value of the newData object without it having a label but the following shows what I am trying to accomplish
         ".validate":"root.child('tasks').hasChild('-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7')",
         }   
       }
     }
    }
  }
```

In this case I am confirming that the newData being added is a valid unique identifier that already exists as a task. In this rule the task will be associated with the queue entity.

If it helps please see my entity map below:
[image: entity-map]

### Alternatively

How can I create an index similar to what I am seeing online in your samples?:

To represent a set of groups that I might  associate with a user....

```
"user_0" : {
....
    "groups" : { 
       "group_id0":true,
       "group_id1":true,
       "group_id2":true
    }
}
```

Following that, how can I validate that a `group_id#` actually exists under my group node elsewhere?

If I can get that answer, I may be able to extrapolate for my needs.

### Update

Based on the accepted answer, I have been able to successfully apply the following rules to achieve the desired outcomes:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":  "false",
    ".write": "(auth.provider != 'anonymous') && (auth != null)",

      "presence": {
        ".read": "(auth.provider != 'anonymous') && (auth != null)",
            ".write": "(auth.provider != 'anonymous') && (auth != null)",
      },

      "queues": { 
        ".read":"(auth != null)",
        ".write": "(auth.provider != 'anonymous') && (auth != null)",
            "$qid": {
                "tasks": {
                "$taskid": {
                    ".validate": "root.child('tasks').child($taskid).exists()"
                }
                }
            }
        },

      "tasks": {
         ".read": "(auth != null)",
          ".write": "(auth.provider != 'anonymous') && (auth != null)",
        "$taskid":{
          "queues":{
              "$qid": {
              ".validate":"root.child('queues').child($qid).exists()"              
              }
            }
          }
        },

       "users": {
          ".read": "(auth != null)",
          ".write": "(auth != null)",
            "$userid":{
            "groups":{
              "$gid": {
              ".validate":"root.child('groups').child($gid).exists()"              
              }
            },
            "roles":{
              "$rid": {
              ".validate":"root.child('roles').child($rid).exists()"              
              }
            },
            "metadata":{
             ".read": "(auth != null)",
             ".write": "(auth.provider != 'anonymous') && (auth != null)",
            }
          }
        },
        "roles": {
          ".read": "(auth != null)",
          ".write": "(auth != null)",
        },
       "groups":{
          ".read": "(auth != null)",
          ".write": "(auth != null)",
            },  
    } //eof-rules  
}
```

Comment: I have clarified the question. If it's unclear please comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add another level to your rules so that you can use a `$` variable for the task ID:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "queues": {
      ".write": "auth.provider != 'anonymous'",
      "$qid": {
        "members": {
          "$taskid": {
            ".validate": "root.child('tasks').hasChild($taskid)"
          }
        }   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use either `set` or `update` to add the task ID to the index:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref("queues/K24395498054-p23/members/-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7")
  .set(true);

firebase
  .database()
  .ref("queues/K24395498054-p23/members")
  .update({ "-KWz2G9JKtwqt5Kn-pL7": true });
```

Comment: +1 for the samples on creating the indexes. Seeing that next to the rules triggered a flag, which I've applied to the entire JSON tree. I've posted my rules so that this Q&A can help the next person.